# Git permissions, do they use the active user's permissions?

Tags: git

I am working with a directory that I'd rather not change ownership of but I have added the user Pi to the group. The permissions are 775 but I still have issues with Git permission denied messages unless I use `sudo`.

Does Git not use my user's permissions to handle everything? Shouldn't it have access becasue I as a group member have

Comment: Btw this is a question for SuperUser site :/

Comment: Have you created a user `Pi`?

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, git uses the priviledges of the uses that runs git.  Have you checked the files mode? Is it 775 as well? `.git` subdir as well?

You may want to run `chmod -R 775 .`

Posting the error message would help to provide a better answer.